# How to push viewcontroller onto navigation stack using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a NavigationViewcontroller set up before a UIViewController, I want to perform a segue programmatically and push another Viewcontroller onto the navigation stack. How can I achieve this?

```
class CreateEventViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    // Updated post with simple answer
    // If you have a Naviagation Controller already instantiated then all you have to do is perform segue and it will push it on the navigation stack   for you
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Event Creation Success", sender: nil)

}
```

EDIT:

Picture of my Storyboard https://i.stack.imgur.com/u97iN.jpg

Comment: If you're using a segue, then you shouldn't be pushing the view controller in code.

Comment: @rdelmar This segue happens when I press a button but I perform other actions when its pressed. I want to segue after that code has executed.

Comment: You need to make the segue from the controller, not the button. In the button's action method, execute the code you need to run before the segue, then call performSegueWithIdentifier. Unless you're passing data to FindHelpViewController, you shouldn't implement prepareForSegue at all.

Comment: @rdelmar Thanks for the clarification, didn't know prepareForSegue was only for passing data between controllers. Do you know how I can instantiate my navigation controller so I can push my viewcontroller on to it?

Comment: You said in your question that you already have a navigation controller, why do you want to instantiate a new one?

Comment: @rdelmar I dont have access to self.navigationController in my current view controller. How do I access my current navigation controller?

Comment: You need to explain what controllers you have. Is the initial controller in the storyboard the navigation controller?

Comment: @rdelmar The navigation controller is in between view controllers. I've added a picture to the original post under my edit for clarification.

Comment: It looks like your current view controller is the one that will get pushed on to the stack from the main controller. You should be able to call performSegue from the current view controller to get to FindHelpViewController. You should have access to self.navigation controller. If log that do you get nil?

Comment: @rdelmar my nav controller has a value: Optional(<UINavigationController: 0x14d52c190>)

Comment: @rdelmar I'm trying to do something like this: self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Event Creation Success", sender: nil)
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(FindHelpViewController(), animated: true). Not sure what the correct syntax is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71549/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-jshah).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I had my navigation controller already instantiated and had a navigation stack all I had to do was performSegueWithIdentifier. No need to pushViewController.

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Event Creation Success", sender: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

`pushViewController` is called only after you already set up a segue by calling `performSegueWithIdentifier`. Put the `pushViewController` call in response to whatever action initializes the segue.

Comment: how can I instantiate my navigation controller so I can push the current view controller on to it?